# NHibernate - Update selected fields of multiple rows with fixed value

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, batch-updates

How can I convert following SQL query to NHibernate?

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET Field1 = "NewValue1",
Field2 = "NewValue2"
WHERE Field3 = FilterValue
```

Assume that `MyTable` contains huge records and above statement affects good percentage of it. It have 50 fields (columns) and some of them hold long strings or reference to other table that I would avoid to load/update unnecessarily.

The way I implemented it now is as below:

```
entities = nhSession.QueryOver<T>().Where(whereJunction).List();
nhSession.SetBatchSize(batchSize);
transaction = nhSession.BeginTransaction();
foreach(entity in entities)
{
    //Modify entity here...
    //nhSession.Update(entity);//No need to call this. Commit() will do.
}
transaction.Commit();
```

Even though batching helps improve performance, this approach have following drawbacks:

- Multiple statements executed ultimately degrading performance.
- Long `foreach` loop.
- Using `nhSession.Flush()` does not overcome the drawbacks.

Advantage is that, updates are reflected in cache.

Another way is `HQL` that I am not considering for following reasons:

- Strings; I do not love them much. That is one of the reason I switched to `ORM`.
- Not strongly typed. Refactoring is difficult.
- Updates are not reflected in cache.
- I am not sure if this honors UoW (NHibernate Transaction).

Yet another way is raw `SQL` that I do not want to use. I want to stick to ORM.

## References:

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780940/batch-update-in-nhibernate): Question and all answers suggests the ways I have already mentioned above.

[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047597/fluent-nhibernate-batch-save): Same that I have already mentioned above.

[Link3](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/manual/en-US/html/batch.html): Same that I have already mentioned above.

**Note:** I have also added 'hibernate' tag assuming similar solution will also available with NHibernate; they are twins by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to pick up to use C# (POCO) entities and have strongly typed code - or to use **HQL**.

In case we want to keep the comfort coming with entities (mapped objects) - the above code (coming with Question) would do the job...

```
entities = nhSession... // load and TRANSFORM to C# objects
foreach(entity in entities)
{
    //Modify entity here...
}
```

If we are ready to use HQL *(strings, or even our custom string builders to automate it more)* we can profit a lot from NHibernate built in API:

### [13.3. DML-style operations](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#batch-direct)

#### [NHibernate – Executable DML](http://ayende.com/blog/4037/nhibernate-executable-dml) by Ayende

And as for example shown here:

- [Update Top n using NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25787388/1679310)

we can do update without loading any data like this

```
ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
ITransaction tx = session.BeginTransaction();
string hqlVersionedUpdate = "update versioned Customer set name = :newName where name = :oldName";
int updatedEntities = s.CreateQuery( hqlUpdate )
        .SetString( "newName", newName )
        .SetString( "oldName", oldName )
        .ExecuteUpdate();
tx.Commit();
session.Close();
```

other [example with delete](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24477039/1679310)

Answer (score 1):

You can now use Linq with NHibernate to do that!

```
//
// Summary:
//     Update all entities selected by the specified query. The update operation is
//     performed in the database without reading the entities out of it.
//
// Parameters:
//   source:
//     The query matching the entities to update.
//
//   expression:
//     The update setters expressed as a member initialization of updated entities,
//     e.g. x => new Dog { Name = x.Name, Age = x.Age + 5 }. Unset members are ignored
//     and left untouched.
//
// Type parameters:
//   TSource:
//     The type of the elements of source.
//
// Returns:
//     The number of updated entities.
public static int Update<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TSource>> expression);
```

In your situation it would mean:

```
session.Query<MyTable>()
            .Where(i => i.Field3 == FilterValue)
            .Update(i => new MyTable { Field1 = "NewValue1", Field2 = "NewValue2" });
```

Comment: From your code, `session.Query<MyTable>()` will load full entity with all 50 fields (columns) some of which hold long strings. Am I right?

Comment: @AmitJoshi Nope that's the thing, it now generates a single update query!

You can also have a look at the .Delete() which does the bulk delete.

We just migrated a project to use those and believe me we're happy.